# work folders access denied

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions

I set up work folders in my organization and that was fine until last week. now I have some issue. One of my clients' works fine but mine and the others' can't access to work folders. I have admin access on the work folder server but I can't using work folders. the server error is:

```
The windows sync service failed to update the current state of an item.
Item \??\E:\Resources\"User Name"; Error code (0x80070005) Access is Denied.
```

Also in client I get this error: `Access is denied.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem using Access Check tool. Using Access Check tool I figured out the modifications applied by my colleague.